# How to show toast in application when a page redirects in android?

Tags: android, android-webview, android-toast

I created an application in android to connect to mongodb. the programs main page consists of a loading a webpage via webview in my system, i used apache as application server. in apache, inside www folder all my php and html pages are there  , and i am able to load those pages, and from that page i can go to all the pages and back via the application itself, my question is that while i go from one page to another, can a toast messege be shown in the screen?. i mean as a notification can a toast message be displayed when a page link is clicked from the emulator?

Answer (score 1):

> my question is that while i go from one page to another, can a toast
>   message be shown in the screen?. i mean as a notification can a toast
>   message be displayed when a page link is clicked from the emulator?

=> Yes you can use [WebViewClient](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebViewClient.html) for your WebView to achieve that. You can write Toast notification code inside [`shouldOverrideUrlLoading()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebViewClient.html#shouldOverrideUrlLoading%28android.webkit.WebView,%20java.lang.String%29) method.

Comment: i am going to a page say mainpage.php when the app starts, then i can go to next page via clicking a link in it. Now please note that my app contains only one java file which is used to load the wep page main.php via webview, what i need is that, when i go from page2.html to page3.html i need to  show a notification in the form of a toast, hope u are clear

Comment: Whatever link will be clicked by user, it executes and goes into `shouldOverrideUrlLoading()`. Hope you understand :)

Answer (score 1):

> i mean as a notification can a toast message be displayed when a page
>   link is clicked from the emulator?

If you want to show a message to User when *"URL are going to be loaded"* you need to assign [WebViewClient](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebViewClient.html) to your `WebView`.

All what you need to do is override for example `onPageStarted()` method<sup>1</sup>:

```
@Override
public void onPageStarted(WebView view, String url, Bitmap favicon) {
   // show message to Use
   Toast.makeText(context, message, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
```

<sup>1</sup><sub>Or also you can override shouldOverrideUrlLoading() method.</sub>

Comment: i am going to a page say mainpage.php when the app starts, then i can go to next page via clicking a link in it. Now please note that my app contains only one java file which is used to load the wep page main.php via webview, what i need is that, when i go from page2.html to page3.html i need to show a notification in the form of a toast, hope u are clear

Comment: @Mukund whathever link you will click on - that method will be called and message will be shown to User.

Comment: so, whatever link i click, same toast message will be shown?, but i need to show toast messages which are dependent to the links clicked, Eg, if i click firstpage.html , i need a toast like "welcome", and if i click 'submit' in sec.html i need to see a toast showing 'form submitted' is that possible?